# CodeIgniter debug function: How can i display/debug formated value of any variable from controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any built-in debug function for codeigniter to use in controller?

In cakephp there is debug($variable) that one can use in controller.

I can use var_dump($variable); or print_r($variable);

But is there any built-in debug function for codeigniter to use in controller to get formatted result of any variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is wherever I want to debug a variable.

```
...
echo "<pre>";
die(print_r($var, TRUE));
...
```

This gives you a nicely formatted version of your variable contents because it retains the formatting when inside of the `<pre>` tag.

So instead of

```
Array ( [0] => "value zero" [1] => "value 1" )
```

you get

```
Array 
(
    [0] => "value zero"
    [1] => "value one"
)
```

etc...

Not sure how much more formatted you can get, unless you're looking for color schemes and animations in your debug statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fire Ignition (with FireBug and FirePHP, or ChromePHP if you use FF instead of Chrome)

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Fire_Ignition/
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html
https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp